# Applying tr:hover but only to a certain class

Tags: css, material-table

I have some CSS that colors a row on my table on hover.

```
tr:hover {
  background: gray !important;
}
```

However, it also highlights the filter row on the table. So I did Inspect and find it has `<tr class="MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-hover"...etc`

So, my question is, how can I modify the above code so that it applies only to that class shown above?

Edit: First attempt at apply class.

```
.MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-hover {
  tr:hover {
    background: gray !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: this could help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Material UI judging by the class names, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "filter row" - if it's the top row with column names, shouldn't it also have those classes? Can you apply a custom class to the rows you want to hover? A little more context would help us provide a helpful answer.

Comment: I am using material-table. The filters row uses a different class. So I only need to know how to apply the above tr:hover to the specific class I mentioned.

Comment: @Lety I have tried to apply the class, but it seems like there are nested classes. I've edited the end of the original post to show what I am now trying, but that doesn't work. Any idea of my error?

Comment: @Jon take a look at answers that are right. 'tr.<classname>' get every tr element with classname, but if selectors are separated by space it search a child of selector with that class...

Comment: Thank you. All is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, please take a look at the documentation for [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

You are having trouble to combine the class with the element's tag.
In this case they are written together like this:

```css
tr.MuiTableRow-hover:hover {
  background: gray !important;
}
```

- When the HTML tag has the class: Write the tag and `.` and then the class
- When the HTML tag has some element inside with a certain class, separate them with a   space
- Do yourself a favor and search for CSS tutorials to teach you the basics. It's not very hard to learn if you can spare the time

A little bit advanced is trusting [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and leaving out `!important`. If your selector is more specific (or your CSS was loaded later) your style will be applied even without use of `!important`.

```css
tr.MuiTableRow-hover:hover {
  background: gray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I did go through some tutorials before, but what threw me off was all the nesting, multiple applied styles, and I should have moved the tr out of the { }.

Comment: Sure that's understandable. It gets confusing trying to combine every lesson at once. CSS only allows for one `{}` per style applied. But there are tools out there which allow for a nested syntax and write that as CSS for you ([SASS/SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/guide) being one, for example). Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The css rule should look like this:

```
tr.MuiTableRow-hover:hover {
   background: gray !important;
}
```

Note that using `!important` is not best practice so better if you try to avoid it if possible